# Order by in Linq

Tags: linq

how can i show null or empty fields  in last by apply Orderby:

here is my code.

```
Var movies = _db.Movies.Orderby(c => c.Category).ThenBy(n => n.Name)
```

Comment: `OrderByDesending` not working??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
Var movies = _db.Movies
    .OrderBy(c => c.Category==null?1:0)
    .Thenby(c => c.Category).ThenBy(n => n.Name)
```